# How to avoid direct stylesheet modifications of plugin

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet, datatables

I have got [datatable](https://datatables.net/) plugin in my application.

To modify the UI look, I have done slight changes to style sheet comes with the plugin.

Changing the style sheet that comes with plugin directly is not a good idea because any updates to the plugin will overwrite any custom changes.

Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could override any of the CSS classes it uses (see full list [here](https://datatables.net/styling/custom_classes)).

Then you just create another CSS file that will be loaded **after** the plugin's css files and override it's classes (or use another CSS technique to achieve higher priority to your CSS).

For example:

In the original DataTables CSS (`demo_table.css`) file you can find:

```
.sorting_desc_disabled
{
     background: url('../images/sort_desc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right;
}
```

Say you want to have another arrow icon, you need to create your own CSS file (`my_demo_table.css`) with:

```
.sorting_desc_disabled
{
     background: url('../images/my_own_disabled_arrow.png') no-repeat center right;
}
```

Again, you'll have to make sure your custom CSS will be loaded after the original CSS, or leverage [CSS Specifity Rules](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to have your custom styles higher priority over the original style.

Comment: any sample examples please

Comment: I revised my answer with example.

Comment: Thats cool, thank you so much. i will try this steps, thanks lot

Comment: i have one doubt in this, first i'm loading site.css and later i'm loading datatable.css files, so in this case first i need to load datatable.css and later i have to load my site.css to gain access to ovveride right?

Comment: yes. but i don't think relying on stylesheets load order is recommended. you better override using `CSS Specifity Rules` (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Answer (score 0):

Write the style changes you required in a separate stylesheet with selectors of a higher precedence than those in the default DataTables stylesheet.

Comment: any sample examples please